# Setting covariates to the mean for marginal effects using ggpredict

Tags: r, regression, probability, glm, marginal-effects

I have some data (df):

```
inter out time int
0     1   21   0
0     0   32   0
0     1   44   0
0     0   59   0
0     1   88   0
0     1   111  0
0     0   54   0
1     0   63   63
1     1   73   73
1     1   83   83
1     0   93   93
1     1   52   52
1     0   33   33
1     1   10   10
```

And I run a [glm](/questions/tagged/glm) model:

```
m <- glm(out ~ inter + time + int, data = df, family = binomial(link = "logit"))
```

The model coefficients are:

```
  Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept) -1.00916    1.82200  -0.554    0.580
inter        2.00906    2.64959   0.758    0.448
time         0.02293    0.03010   0.762    0.446
int         -0.03502    0.04215  -0.831    0.406
```

I want to get the marginal effects, which according to my understanding is the predicted probabilities at certain levels holding other variables constant, which in this case is 0 vs. 1 for my binary predictor, 'inter'. If this in incorrect, please let me know. According to [https://rdrr.io/cran/ggeffects/man/ggpredict.html], "All remaining covariates that are not specified in terms are held constant (see 'Details')". The mean of time and int are 58.29 and 29.07, respectively, so the formula to get the predicted probabilities is:

```
Level 0:                                              
sum = -1.00916 + (.02293 * 58.29) + (-.03502 * 29.07)       
sume = exp(sum)
sumee <- sume/(1+sume)
sumee = 0.33

Level 1:
sum = -1.00916 + 2.00906 + (.02293 * 58.29) + (-.03502 * 29.07) 
sume = exp(sum)
sumee <- sume/(1+sume)
sumee = 0.79
```

The predicted probability holding other variables constant is 0.79 for level 1 compared to 0.33 for level 0, which is exactly what these [ggpredict](/questions/tagged/ggpredict) statements produce:

```
ggpredict(m, terms = c("inter", "time [mean]"))
ggpredict(m, terms = c("inter"))
```

However, when I specify 'int' at the mean with "int [mean]", it produces different results:

```
ggpredict(m, terms = c("inter", "time [mean]", "int [mean]"))
ggpredict(m, terms = c("inter", "int [mean]"))
```

It says level 0 has a predicted probability of 0.19, compared to 0.64 for level 1. Why? Shouldn't all four commands produce the same results since [r](/questions/tagged/r) automatically calculates covariates at the mean? Using other functions for 'int', such as min and max `ggpredict(m, terms = c("inter", "time [mean]", "int [min]"))` produces predictable results based on the formula.

Comment: Do you have a reproducible example?

Comment: You can reproduce the above by copying and pasting the data and code.

Comment: I tried to, but I got different results.

Comment: Sorry, the int variable was incorrect. It's supposed to be an interaction term between inter and time.